# How to filter the intent for a certain activity

Tags: android, android-intent

**MainActivity.java :**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Profile_view.class);
    intent.putExtra("user",username);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**Profil_view :**

```
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    if(intent!=null)
    {
        String user = intent.getExtras().getString("user");
        Log.i("ProfileView",user);
        DBAdapter dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(Profile_view.this);
        dbAdapter.open();
        String name = dbAdapter.getName(user);
        full_name.setText(name);
        username_display.setText(dbAdapter.getUserName(user));
        mail_display.setText(dbAdapter.getMail_id(user));
        date_of_birth_display.setText(dbAdapter.get_date_of_birth(user));
        //country_display.setText(dbAdapter.get_country(user));
        dbAdapter.close();
    }
```

I have a situation here at which i register the user details and move to `profile_view` page to display it and similarly when i login at the main activity, it matches with the current username from the database and displays his user details in the `profile_view` page. So `profile_view` can be reached from both `registration_page` and `main_activity`.

The list of methods in `profile_view` should work for both registration page and main 
activity page but it cause of the intent from the main activity, it throws me a null 
pointer exception when i reach from registration page.

Comment: You can pass one string in your intent in your profile_view activity check that whether its register activity or login activity based on that you can execute the code. Please post your code with register activity code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an **attribute** named `hasExtra()` is available for `Intent`. You can make use of that to find out whether an extra is available for it or not.

Try this..

```
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    if(intent!=null)
    {
        if(intent.hasExtra("user"))
        {
             //It means that intent has an extra with tag name - "user".
             //So, it shows that the intent is from MainActivity
             //Do the necessary coding here

             String user = intent.getExtras().getString("user");
             Log.i("ProfileView",user);
             DBAdapter dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(Profile_view.this);
             dbAdapter.open();
             String name = dbAdapter.getName(user);
             full_name.setText(name);
             username_display.setText(dbAdapter.getUserName(user));
             mail_display.setText(dbAdapter.getMail_id(user));
             date_of_birth_display.setText(dbAdapter.get_date_of_birth(user));
             //country_display.setText(dbAdapter.get_country(user));
             dbAdapter.close();
        }
        else
        {
             //It means that intent doesn't have an extra with tag name - "user".
             //So, it shows that the intent is from RegisterActivity
             //Do the necessary coding here
        }
    }
```

description of [hasExtra("")](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#hasExtra%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Vazhga tamilan.  Thanks a lot tamila.

Answer (score 2):

Just put one condition for checking value of intent like below:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    if(intent!=null)
    {
        if(intent.hasExtra("user"))
        {

           //Your Code


         }

     }
```

Comment: Neat and simple pal. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the string in intent from your mainactivity to identify that you are coming from MainActivity as below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Profile_view.class);
intent.putExtra("user",username);
 intent.putExtra("Activity","MainActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

In your profileview activity check for the value as below:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
String value= intent.getString("Activity");
if(intent!=null)
{
  if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("MainActivity"))
   {
     String user = intent.getExtras().getString("user");
    Log.i("ProfileView",user);
    DBAdapter dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(Profile_view.this);
    dbAdapter.open();
    String name = dbAdapter.getName(user);
    full_name.setText(name);
    username_display.setText(dbAdapter.getUserName(user));
    mail_display.setText(dbAdapter.getMail_id(user));
    date_of_birth_display.setText(dbAdapter.get_date_of_birth(user));
    //country_display.setText(dbAdapter.get_country(user));
    dbAdapter.close();
   }
     else{
         //Comes from Login activity
        }
  }
```

Comment: @GrlsHu, Thanks mate. Looks like this will work for sure. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @San Try out it will surely work . Let me know if any help needed.